# How to hide Series Name in HighCharts Tooltip when using pointFormatter

Tags: highcharts

How to hide Series Name in HighCharts Tooltip when using pointFormatter

Please find below my JSfiddle example
link:

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/3peLzu6s/2/][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `tooltip.headerFormat` as a null should solve this case.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a9j4v3b7/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.headerFormat

Comment: Thanks a lot Sebastian for your help, i am facing another challenge now that is, i am trying to display highCharts tooltip in a table format using below pointFormate method but its not working, please advise how to display   tooltip: {
    headerFormat: null,
    pointFormatter: function() {
     const x = this.x,
     y = this.y; } }

Comment: @MuraliButchacha could you reproduce the whole code to be sure that we are working on the same thing?

Comment: tooltip: {
    headerFormat: null,
    pointFormatter: function() {
     const x = this.x,
     y = this.y; //create html table tags to display table in tool tip 
   } }

Comment: i am trying something like below'<table>'+
_.forEach(points, (point) => {
 '<tr><td>'+ point.name + ':' + point.AvailableUnits + '<tr><td>');
 });
 '</table>'+

Comment: Could you reproduce it on the online editor?